# Angular Error setInterval: don't clear interval or don't do something that i don't understand

Tags: angular, setinterval, intervals

In my code i se interval in this way

```
this.myInterval = setInterval(() => {
    if (this.area != null) {
      this.doSomething.setSomething(this.area);
    } else this.getArea();
  }, 9000);
```

then

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    clearInterval(this.myInterval );
}
```

but when i change page it always continue to call this.doSomething.setSomething every 9 sec...
and get error `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: makeInstance(...) is null`

what's wrong???

Comment: What is `makeInstance`? If it is code it is not shared in your question.

Comment: don't know... don't have it in my code... it say this error and the refer is on the line of "this.doSomething.setSomething(this.area)"...